# rewrite file's MIME-Type in .htaccess isn't working

Tags: ios, apache, .htaccess, ios-universal-links, universal-link

I want to upload an AASA (apple-app-site-association).
The problem I'm having is that I can't set the MIME-Type. I placed the file in the root `/` **and** the `.well-known` folder without an extension. After that I tried (like I did with success on an other hosting provider) to change the MIME-Type to `application/json`.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# BEGIN Thunermay (Admin)
# set apple-app-site-association as application/json for Apple's crawler
<Files "apple-app-site-association">
    ForceType 'application/json'
</Files>
# END Thunermay
```

When I used an AASA validator ([this](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) and [this](https://yurl.chayev.com) one), I can't get the right `content-type`. The second one shows me at least that the file is parsed but without a content-type:

```
No Redirect:              Pass
Content-type:             [] 
JSON Validation:          Pass
JSON Schema:              Pass
```

I don't know where my mistake in the `.htaccess` is nor do I know how to potentially debug the `.htaccess`

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out an alternative:

Instead of using `ForceType` I used:

```
<Files "apple-app-site-association">
    Header set Content-type 'application/json'
</Files>
```

I don't know why the other alternative didn't work